# Is it possible to find a cubic supercell for a non-cubic crystal structure?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, crystallography, periodic-system, periodic-boundary-conditions

Suppose that we have a crystal material with a non-cubic unit cell. E.g. $\alpha \neq \beta \neq \gamma \neq 90^{\circ}$. Is it possible to find a supercell such that $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 90^{\circ}$?

If no, can you explain why is not possible?

Comment: It is a symmetry issue: you cannot fill the space with atoms (you cannot reproduce all the geometry operations in both).

Comment: Some are possible, some are not, depending on the crystal structure.